# What's the best way to calculate strength of fit of these curves?

Tags: python, statistics

The green line is a fit to the red data points. What is the best way to calculate the strength of fit for something like this?

There are lots of raw points from 0-100, as the x-axis gets larger the number of data points tends to decrease, and the residual tends to get worse.

The number of red data points is always variable, and it stops at various times on the x-axis, but the fit always goes back to 0 on the y-axis.

I'm trying to get a sense for how good the fit is for one example vs another.

I figured the average error could be good, but there's way more data points 0-100 so that will heavily influence the average. Also the error could be low, but stop very early, which would go uncaptured in that scenario.

[image: Data]

Comment: What's "strength of fit"?

Comment: I'm trying to find a quantitative metric to compare various examples for how closely the green line represents the red data points.

Answer (score 0):

In my grad school days, we used the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov Goodness-of-Fit Test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm). Essentially you are comparing the Cumulative Distribution of your data to the Cumulative Distribution of your fit function evaluated with the same number of points.  Enjoy the rabbit hole.